# CodeIgniter4 db->save() method

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-4

I'm doing some tries in CI4 and I got stuck saving data into the database.

I'm trying as below:

```
use App\Models\UserModel;                                                                          
     ...                                                                   
       $model = new UserModel();
            $newUser = [                    
                'firstname' => $this->request->getVar('firstname'),
                'lastname' => $this->request->getVar('lastname'),
                'email' => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                'password' => $this->request->getVar('password')
            ];
            $model->save( $newUser );
```

The error shown is:
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

and if we look at the query arguments, it's generating a query with no params:

```
$query  INSERT INTO `users` () VALUES ('')
```

User table:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      `firstname` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
      `lastname` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

UserModel

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;


class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $returnType = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

    protected $allowedFields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'updated_at'];

    protected $useTimestamps = false;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = '';

    protected $validationRules    = [];
    protected $validationMessages = [];
    protected $skipValidation     = false;

    protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];


    protected function beforeInsert( array $data )
    {
        $this->_hashPassword( $data );
    }

    protected function beforeUpdate( array $data )
    {
        $this->_hashPassword( $data );
    }

    protected function _hashPassword( array $data )
    {
        if( isset($data['data']['password']))
            $data['data']['password'] = password_hash( $data['data']['password'] , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: This simply means your newUser data is empty. You should also post how you are fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping, the issue was in DB port config , by default codeigniter bring it as 3306 and  in wampServer it is used by MariaDB I just change it to 3308 (MySqlDB) and it works fine.